# How to read non-latin characters from QSettings in QT

Tags: qt

When i try read non-latin characters (e. g. russian) from QSettings in QT i have wrong values, something like "Ð\224Ð°Ð´Ð°Ð´". How to do it? Please, help.
I use ubuntu.

Comment: Add the code that you’re using the write and read the values.

Answer (score 2):

Try first reading byte array and then convert it to string from UTF8, e.g.:

```
QSettings settings("filename.ini", QSettings::IniFormat);

QByteArray  ba  = settings.value("goup/key").toByteArray();
QString     str = QString::fromUtf8(ba.data(), ba.length());
```